# What is the best design practise to create tables from same controller using same actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controllers

I have a project that involved genealogy.  It starts by asking you questions you (current user), then the same questions about your father, then exactly the same questions about your mother and goes on until grandparents of both sides.

Unfortunately, I have tried 3 different approaches and implementations, each time correcting past mistakes as I am pretty new to rails.

I would like to get a recommendation/guidance from this community regarding the best design approach that I should follow having design problems.

So I think that the best way is to come up with different tables to benefit later when I need to put this info in a single family tree.  So, one table for the current user, one for the father, mother, etc having a model for each table BUT using a single controller because I have exactly the same html.erb form and each time changes the headers to adapt the sibling question.

I had successfully created the flow and actions such as new, create, show etc BUT my problem is the following:

The flow of my questions is consecutive, and at the very end shows a family tree.  Therefore when the user clicks continue, the data are saved in the equivalent table of my database and the flow continues for the next table.

I am stuck for more than 8 hours on how to make the create method change from father to mother having this code:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_father'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :dob, :location)
  end
```

where users is the name of Users_Controller and 'new_father' is a view in the same controller (new_father.html.erb).  Other views exist like current_user, new_mother etc.

So, the first redirection is achieved successfully as data are stored in the database (first redirection = going from current user to his father), but then I can't manage to go from father to mother in the same controller and the form stays stacked in the new_father.html.erb view having the following code:

```
def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
          redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_mother'
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :dob, :location)
  end
```

But then I need more controllers to perform this or a different action in the same controller called create_mother. But I tried everything with not success.

Can someone please help me (firstly) on the redirect_to method best practise, particularly if I need more controllers with same methods or the same controller with different methods, or the same controller same functions (I tried this and I am getting the error of "more redirections or renderings in a single function") and secondly if what is the best design to follow for this particular situation where I need exactly the same fields and actions but in different tables having different redirections each time.

My routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # The first page providing information about the current user (novice genealogist).
  get 'users/new'

  # The rest of the pages asking information to form the tree.
  get 'fathers/new_father'
  get 'mothers/new_mother'

  # TODO
  # get 'users/new_grandfather_m'
  # get 'users/new_grandmother_m'

  # The input windows that the user lands on need to create a new record in the database.
  get  '/signup',              to: 'users#new'
  get  '/new_father',          to: 'fathers#new_father'
  get  '/new_mother',          to: 'mothers#new_mother'

  # TODO
  # get  '/new_grandfather_m',   to: 'users#new'
  # get  '/new_grandfather_m',   to: 'users#new'

  # This page will serve as the tree showing information from the above input.
  get  '/tree'  ,              to: 'users#show'

  # Used to update the database by creating records with the above info.
  post '/signup',              to: 'users#create'
  post '/new_father',          to: 'fathers#create_father'
  post '/new_mother',          to: 'mothers#create_mother'

  # TODO
  # post '/new_grandfather_m',   to: 'users#create'
  # post '/new_grandmother_m',   to: 'users#create'

  # The database of our system.
  resources :users

  # The homepage.
  root 'users#new'

end
```

The other actions are: (basically I had made new controllers for each relation)

```
class FatherController < ApplicationController

  # Creates a new instance of the user object (not a record).

  def new_father
    @father = User.new
  end


  # Creates a new record in the database by filling the fields of the new object instance
  # with data.

  def create_father
    @father = User.new(father_params)
    if @father.save
      #redirect_to @user
      redirect_to :controller => 'mothers', :action => 'new_mother'
    else
      render 'new_father'
    end
  end


  # A private method to pass the parameters in the new object instance.

  private

  def father_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :dob, :location)
  end


  # Extracts information from the database.

  def show_father
    @father = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

- NOTE:

I don't have to make relations etc, the important thing is to come up with a really simple tree to show the data of the user and to learn rails therefore relations one to one, one to many, many to many are not important.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add your `new_mother` and `new_father` actions code to your question.

Comment: Please also add your routes.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have updated the question with the code you asked but it is not important to include relations because this is a simple app and the main objective is the final view where there exist a simple tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `create` actions which, following your description, reside in different controllers. Both try to redirect to the `UserController` though which is inconsistent with the previous. You should add your controllers and routes code to your question to remove ambiguity.

The `new_father` and `new_mother` are not the views of your controller but the actions. When you do something like this at the end of an action:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_mother'
```

The browser gets a redirect status with the url it should visit next, something like this:

```
Location: http://localhost:3000/users/new_mother
```

the browser then makes a new request at that url, meaning that if you have your routes in place, your `UserController`'s `new_mother` action will get executed. Your `new_mother` and `new_father` should be actions within your `UserController` unless you do some routing hacks. To reiterate, just in case, this happens as a completely new request, unrelated to the first one that returned the redirection status.

When you call `redirect_to` or `render`, Rails does not yet send the response to the browser, instead it marks its internal response structure with some data and goes on with the rest of your action's code. It is only when the complete action code has been executed, the response is sent back. By its design Rails complains if you call those methods more than once within your action as it treats this as a potential mistake in the action code.

---

On the design:

There are persons and relations in your domain. Persons have the same attributes, be it a user, father or mother or any other relative. Your domain does not dictate that persons need to be distributed among different tables. In fact, what you are mainly after is the relation type between family members. Mother, father, sister, nephew, etc. are relations between a pair of people. It would then make sense to present these relations as a model:

```
# simplistic representation
create_table "relations" do |t|
  t.integer  "to_person_id"
  t.integer  "is_person_id"
  t.string  "relation_type"
end
```

`relation_type` field would carry the kinship type as a string, e.g. 'father'.

Although this would be one proper way to build a full-scale genealogy tree application, it is also more complex. It would involve single-table has-many associations and recursive SQL queries, both of which are rather advanced topics.

There are existing gems, handling this kind of schema. Some of them are [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree), [acts-as-dag](https://github.com/mleventi/acts-as-dag).

Comment: I prefer a handy and clear solution with as less magic as possible to understand the MVC of this case with even a table for each person (i will go up to grandparents not further) and tell me if it is good to have a different model for each table and a different controller and do the redirections inside the create functions using: redirect_to :controller => 'mothers', :action => 'new_mother'

Comment: I also update the question with code from routes and user controller

Comment: For simplicity sake and for learning purpose your approach is perfectly valid. It's fine to have different models and controllers for `fathers` and `mothers`, especially because you're not planning to go beyond grandparents. In this regard your controllers and routes look good.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Nic and I hope to reach your level one day.

Answer (score 1):

Having different models/tables for same data is not a best approach. I think you should only  need 2 tables to handle all of it (Of course one table for `questions`).
One table should be `users` in which all of the users will be stored. Every user will has the reference to it's `mother` and it's `father` 
It can be achieved by self join/inheritance.
Then you need a table for `answers` in this table all of the answers for all of the users will be stored. All of the answer whether they are for `mother` , or `father` , or `grand parents`.
You only need an extra column to differentiate the type of the answer whether it's for mother/himself/father or grand parents.

Every `answer` will belong to the `user` who gave that answer and will belong to the `question`

So basically here is a raw implementation for this schmea.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :answers
belongs_to :mother , class_name: 'User' , foreign_key: 'mother_id' #This is telling the user belongs to a mother and it's stored in same table. And mother reference will be stored in mother_id column. So user table should have a column mother_id

belongs_to: father , class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'father_id' #This is telling the user belongs to a father and it's stored in same table. And father reference will be stored in father_id column. So user table should have a column father_id

has_many :children ,->(user){ where("users.father_id ? or users.mother_id = ?",user.id)} #Every user can have many children. Whether it's a mother or a father 

def grand_father_from_father_side
    father && father.father 
end

def grand_father_from_mother_side
    mother && mother.father
end

#Similary you can get grammy like mother.mother
end


class Question < ActiceRecord::Base
has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user

#There will be a question_for column in answer table which will tell you this answer was posted for which relation i-e Mother , Father or User Himself

end
```

now In user controller it's pretty straight forward. You only need a single view which will be called for every type of answer whether it's for user or his parents or his grand father. Simply put a hidden field in the form which will tell you the type of the answer and it will be stored in answer table.

So if user is answering for her mother it's value will be 'Mother' and so on.

Then you can filter all the user answer with '

`user.answers.where(answer_type: 'Mother')` this will return all the answers for a user which he answered for his mother.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Not required to include relations, I am novice in rails and it is my very first backend framework and I have this project with objective to show a tree with those relations.  I prefer a handy and clear solution with as less magic as possible to understand the MVC of this case with even a table for each person (i will go up to grandparents not further) and tell me if it is good to have a different model for each table and a different controller and do the redirections inside the create functions using: redirect_to :controller => 'mothers', :action => 'new_mother'

Comment: I also update the question with code from routes and user controller

Comment: As I mentioned earlier it's not a best practice to do what you are trying to accomplish. But as you learning Rails So it's okay to have multiple models and controller and playing with them. 
After the completion of this task you your self have the idea why it was not a good idea to do it

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Qaisar and I hope to reach your level one day.